# Disable keyboard "return" key in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Now in SwiftUI, keyboard automatically dismisses when we hit the **return** key on the keyboard.
In my case, I want the user not to accidentally dismiss the keyboard by hitting the **return** key.

There's no any keyboard type in `.keyboardType(.****)` without the **return** key

So, is there any way to disable the **return** key from dismissing the keyboard or is there any way to remove the **return** key from the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

`.keyboardType(.twitter)` is what you are looking for.